# How to insert data from text box in database in asp.net mvc

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-4

```
Index.cshtml code for text box
 @Html.LabelFor(m => m.ValidFromDate, "ValidFromDate")
     @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.ValidFromDate)
```

I don't get idea how to insert this text box value to database

Comment: you have to use `@Form.beginForm` and need one submit button, when clicking on submit it will again call controller where you will get model in which you will get your values.

Comment: are you use code first?

Comment: here i'm also using upload.yes using code first

Comment: do you want to use Ajax post or a normal post ?

Comment: Please paste you complete html

Comment: Hi @ruchipathak I pasted a sample code I tested it and it should be fine . Please check my answer .

Comment: @ruchipathak your issue solved I mentioned my answer few days back

Answer (score 0):

Let's assume you have a table names Users in the db. First we will create a `POCO` which will represent this table as follows:

```
public class User
{
    public string Username { get; set; }
    public DateTime ValidFromDate { get; set; }
    //more propteries
}
```

Now let's assume we have a view named Create. In this view you will pass the `User` class we've created as your model. So your view should look something like this.

```
@model Models.User

@{
ViewBag.Title = "User";
}

<div>
@using (Html.BeginForm("Create", "User"))
{
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()

    @Html.LabelFor(m => m.Username)
    @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Username)

    @Html.LabelFor(m => m.ValidFromDate)
    @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.ValidFromDate) 

    <button type="submit">Submit</button>
}
</div>
```

Now you want to get all the values from this view inside your controller action. We will go ahead and create a controller named `UserController` and inside this controller we will provide `GET` and `POST` methods our `Create`

```
//This is our GET action for the view 
public ActionResult Create()
{
   User user = new User();

   return View(user); //we pass in the user object to the view
}

[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
//when you click submit this is the action that will get hit
public ActionResult Create(User model)
{
   if (!ModelState.IsValid)
       return View(model);

   string userName = model.Username;
   DateTime validFrom = model.ValidFromDate;

   //save to db here. I'm not sure if you're making direct calls or using entity framework or similar framework

   return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home"); //this will redirect the user to home. You can return a view or redirect user somewhere else.
}
```

Comment: hey here i have simple excel file upload with this i have a text box  through which  i just enter date and choose the upload file .after click upload button will be update the sql database table .here upload botton only update the uploaded data not the text box input date.

Comment: You can use  enctype  multipart/form-data  inside your beginform and get the file sin Request object   Html.BeginForm("", "", FormMethod.Post, new { enctype = "multipart/form-data" }

Comment: @ruchipathak ifd you like i can share some demo code .

Comment: @ruchipathak ok I will share it please give me 20 mins

Comment: @ruchipathak I pasted the code please check I hope it will be useful .

Comment: @Yashveer Singh here i m facing the same problem while saving text box data

Comment: @ruchipathak :-did your first problem resolved ? did you get File in request.Files property ? if yes plz mark this answer and ask new question . this way it is better . please paste you complete code in new question . And pleease test my code first andadd more properties in my FileUploadModel class

Comment: @YashveerSingh  file upload is in working condition but the problem i faced is in text box from where i insert a date and update in db.

Comment: @ruchipathak  thats great so one problem is tackled . can you please share your code and what error are you getting . Please take a screen shot and paste here then only I can answer . Also it would be better that you close this question and ask another .

Comment: @ruchipathakshare you cshtml file and on the crome open your network tab and check the content of the request if you dont find texbox value in that request then it means som problem while posting the data .

Answer (score 0):

Here we go . I tested this and it returned me the model properties along with files posted  .

```
//-- this is the controller
    public class FileUploadDemoController : Controller
    {
        //
        // GET: /FileUploadDemo/

        public ActionResult Index()
        {
            return View();
        }

        -- here you can name the method as you like to I justuse postform
        [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult PostForm(FileUploadModel model)
        {
            Request.Files is the object which contrins all files which you posted from the form when you hit submit buuton after selecting excel file.
            if (Request.Files != null && Request.Files.Count > 0)
            {
               // here you have files attached and model propertied now you can go to db and perform operation which you need to do 
            }

            return View("Index", model);
        }
    }
```

-- This is the model which I use to bind the form

```
        namespace WebApplication1.Models
    {
        public class FileUploadModel
        {
            public string Name { get; set; }
            public string ValidFromDate { get; set; }
        }
    }
```

-- Finaly the cshml file . The import point is to use new { enctype = "multipart/form-data" } inside BeginForm .

```
          // the page from where you will post the data . Please change you model class in place of FileUploadModel I created ot for me .
```

//           Please not I didnt not use any datepicket to keep it simple if you enter date  like 01-01-2015 this to test .

```
        @model WebApplication1.Models.FileUploadModel

        @using (Html.BeginForm("PostForm", "FileUploadDemo", FormMethod.Post, new { enctype = "multipart/form-data" }))
        { 

        <div class="panel">
            <div class="panel-body">
                <div class="form-group row">
                    <div class="col-md-2 form-label">
                        <label>Name:</label>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-6">
                        @Html.TextAreaFor(x => x.Name, new { @class = "form-control" })
                    </div>

                </div>

                <div class="form-group row">
                    <div class="col-md-2 form-label">
                        <label>Date</label>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-6">
                        @Html.TextAreaFor(x => x.ValidFromDate, new { @class = "form-control" })
                    </div>

                </div>
                <div class="col-md-10">
                    <div class="form-group row">
                        <div class="col-md-2 form-label">
                            <label>Select File<i class="required-field">*</i>:</label>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-md-8">
                            <input type="file" class="file-upload" style="margin: 0px;" hidden="hidden" accept=".xlsx" name="file" id="file" />
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="form-group row">
                    <div class="col-md-3 pull-right text-right">
                        <button class="btn btn-primary" id="process-submission"  type="submit" 
                                >Submit</button>

                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        }
```